# Indexes for the Not Equal and Like

Tags: sql, oracle

I hope the optimizer don't use the indexes If the column uses the Not equal in the where clause, But As per the explain plan the not equal also using the Index search.

Someone Please confirm?

Comment: Could you provide the explain plan and the query?

Comment: You probably wouldn't want an index range scan for a not equal comparison, but you may still benefit from something like a fast full index scan.  As JSapkota said, you'll need to post more details, like the explain plan and query.

Comment: Is it a Bitmap Index?